# Login failed at Google Spreadsheet API with Net::Google::Spreadsheets

Tags: perl, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to read out (later maybe even write) into a Google Spreadsheet with Net::Google::Spreadsheets.

The most boilerplate script dies with "Login failed" and no error:

```
use Net::Google::Spreadsheets;

my $service = Net::Google::Spreadsheets->new(
  username => 'myusername@googlemail.com',
  password => 'mypassword'
);
```

All I'm getting is

```
Net::Google::AuthSub login failed
```

Sadly, I don't know how one would diagnose or fix this issue. Anyone?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

May be because of SSL certificate checking. You can skip the test with:

```
$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;
```

Though really you should set the certificate authorities correctly, as per the message returned by the Net::Google::AuthSub module:

> Can't verify SSL peers without knowing which Certificate Authorities
>   to trust
>
> This problem can be fixed by either setting the PERL_LWP_SSL_CA_FILE
>   envirionment variable or by installing the Mozilla::CA module.
>
> To disable verification of SSL peers set the
>   PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME envirionment variable to 0.  If you do
>   this you can't be sure that you communicate with the expected peer.